# S3.upload() in Lambda nodeJS 12

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to upload something to S3 using lambda, the part of the code that isn't working is as follows...

```
//...Other Code that works...
await s3.upload(s3Params, function (e, d) {
            console.log("Here");
            if (!e) {
                msg = "Example1";
                code = 1;
            }else{
                msg = "Example2:";
                code = 2;
            }
        }).promise();
```

The issue is, the function doesn't seem to run. The console does not log 'here', msg and code remain null, BUT the upload works, the data appears in S3 and is complete. What am I doing wrong?

Side note: Please explain if you can as I am new to this and trying to learn, so please also include any best practice tips. I have an almost identical piece of code uploading to DynamoDB (which works perfectly)... is there best practise for doing both of these uploads?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that you can mix callbacks and promises. Here's the same code using only promises:

```
//...Other Code that works...
try {
  await s3.upload(s3Params).promise();
  msg = "Example1";
  code = 1;
} catch(e) {
  msg = "Example2:";
  code = 2;
} finally {
  console.log('Here')
}
```